# Problems running an image of worpress in docker on Raspberry PI

Tags: wordpress, docker

I'm trying to run an image of wordpress in a docker, on my raspberry PI 3. I install the docker, add my 'pi' user to the docker group and I can run images like "hello-world" but when I try to run an image of wordpress I got error of premissions like this:

```
tar: ./wp-blog-header.php: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-signup.php: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: ./index.php: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: ./wp-config-docker.php: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: .: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Someone can help me with this error, I can't understand what kind of permissions are missing... ?

I'm using the latest image of wordpress, I just type: "docker run wordpress" I don't know if we need to check something in the image...

Thanks

Comment: What wordpress docker image are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm using the latest image of wordpress, I just type: "docker run wordpress" I don't know if we need to check something in the image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds to me like the semi-recent seccomp issues that have plagued containers thanks to libc updates using new syscalls; see https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.13.0#time64_requirements and/or https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.14.0#faccessat2 for details.

I would suggest updating Docker, runc, and libseccomp on your host, which will likely resolve this.

If you want a quick test to verify that this is indeed the problem and updating will likely fix it, you can try running the container again with `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined` -- if that succeeds, you definitely want to update your host.